# AngularJS input time string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express

My Database Object looks like this:

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5646ea1f83abfba81202f4c2"} , "zeit" : "671" , "name" : "nnnn" , "sprache" : "nnnnnn" , "__v" : 0}
```

In this lines of code my number will be converted to an date

```
     app.get("/rest/data/:id", function (req, res) {
            Person.findById(req.params.id, function (err, person) {
            person.zeit = minutesToDate(person.zeit);
            res.send(person);
        });
    });
});

 function minutesToDate(minutes) {
    var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
    var minute = minutes % 60;
    var date = (new Date(1970, 0, 1, hours, minute, 0));
    console.log(date);
    return date;
}
```

Now my Object looks like this:

```
{__v: 0,_id: "5646ea1f83abfba81202f4c2",name: "nnnn",sprache: "nnnnnn", zeit: "1970-01-01T10:11:00.000Z"}
```

I want to put it in this input:

```
<input ng-model="controller.person.zeit" class="form-control" type="time"/>
```

But I get this error from angular:

```
Error: [ngModel:datefmt] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/ngModel/datefmt?p0=1970-01-01T10%3A11%3A00.000Z
    at Error (native)
```

**I guess it is because my Date-Object is a string. Could it be the problem? How can i fix it?**

Comment: I cannot really see where you have defined controller.person.zeit. If it comes from the DB you need to parse it again to a Date after you converted it to ISO.

Comment: It is define in my '$routeProvider .when("/person",
            {
                templateUrl: "person/person.view.html",
                controller: "PersonController as controller"
            })'

Answer (score 0):

you can use
[Date format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

Also 
[Time format](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

And about binding to template use it from this example

[Angular time template](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

Comment: Is it not a Problem that zeit is storred in MongoDB as a string?

Answer (score 0):

Yes indeed, if you follow the link in your error message you see that a Date is expected.
You have to handle the conversion between your string representation and the date format. I would recommend using moment.js (http://momentjs.com)

Comment: okay, i added this line of code `person.zeit = moment(person.zeit).format();` but the error is still there.

Comment: `moment.isDate(person.zeit)` is true, but angularjs throw still the same error.

Comment: Are you sure? moment().format() always gives you a string representation not a date. And moment.isDate(obj) checks if obj is a native date object.

Comment: `moment.isDate(person.zeit)` is false. you are right, it was my mistake. If i store zeit as a date in my database, the "ngModel datefmt"-error still exists. How can i put zeit in my `<input type="time" ng-model="controller.person.zeit">` and store it as a number?